# Quick application switch (Command-Tab) messed up

Tags: system-settings, shortcut

My quick application switching, using Command-Tab, isn't starting at the most recently opened/focused application. Instead it does the opposite. It goes to the application I opened least recently. How do I fix this?

Comment: Remove any "utilities" like Alfred or Candy Bar. Restart your Mac.

Comment: I don't have any of those

Comment: Did you tried restarting your Mac?

Comment: [These errors are now worse on Sierra.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/257369/4395)